# Apache2 restart/start error

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I am trying to restart Apache2, but whenever I run the command, this happens:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Now, when I type "systemctl status apache2.service", it prints out this:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-09-26 14:40:35 CEST; 1min 33s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2183 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2490 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk apache2[2490]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk apache2[2490]: Output of config test was:
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk apache2[2490]: [Mon Sep 26 14:40:35.250008 2016] [:crit] [pid 2501:tid 140245312874368] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk apache2[2490]: AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk apache2[2490]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk apache2[2490]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 26 14:40:35 Asterisk systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My error log (What I think it is my Error Log)
http://hastebin.com/axalecoves.rb

I'm using a Ubuntu Server, running 16.04.1.
If any of you know what I am doing wrong, please do help me.
This happens whenever I run the `sudo a2enmod php7.0` command. When I do `a2dismod php7.0`I can start it again just fine...
As I said, if anyone knows anything about this, please do help me :)

Comment: Moved my "answer" to the comments which makes more sense ...

That's a first hint `Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.`

But to be sure pay attention to the line saying `The Apache error log may have more information.`Could you please show us the content of the apache error log?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/iganelojor.rb - I believe that is the log.

Answer (score 1):

As said by [Wiki Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#Apache_is_running_a_threaded_MPM.2C_but_your_PHP_Module_is_not_compiled_to_be_threadsafe.):

You need to replace `mpm_event_module` with `mpm_prefork_module`.
Open file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and edit like follows:

```
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

Then restart Apache Service.

Comment: I don't have any httpd folder. Do you know why?

Comment: Try with `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Otherwise use: `a2dismod mpm_event` and `a2enmod mpm_prefork`, `service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Where would I place the LoadModule command though?

Comment: Nevermind. What you told me works ;) Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw those commands create a `symlink` in the `mods-enabled` folder, in such a way enabling the mode chosen. If you resolved the case, accept my answer ;)